How to specify value and pass variables into script in SSIS project in Visual Studio
I have created a new SSIS project in Visual Studio 2019.  I want to use a script to open and refresh some Excel files.
I added 3 package variables, filePath, fileName, fileExt.
The path will likely be the same for all of them, but the filename and extension may differ (.xls vs .xlsx).
So two questions.
First is, can I set the variable within the script parameters?
User::fileName=@"This File"
Second, how do I properly reference them?
m_objExcel = new Excel.Application();
m_objBooks = (Excel.Workbooks)m_objExcel.Workbooks;
m_objBook = (Excel.Workbook)m_objBooks.Open((string)Dts.Variables["$package::fileName"].Value,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing);
Thread.Sleep(3000);


In the C# Script task as long as you set the variables ad Read Only  (you can access them) or Readh Write you can update them.
To reference them I would create a string variable first in your C# code, and set the value passed from the package to the variable value (make it easier to see/read and you wont have to keep calling back to SSIS variable if you set it as a string in your code).
To access Variables from inside script task this is how I do it:
To get value passed to script task:
String YourVariableName = Dts.Variables["User::VariableNamePassed"].Value.ToString();

To update variable from script task back to SSIS:
Dts.Variables["User::VariableNamePassedBack"].Value = VariableYouSetToPassBack.ToString();

